# Counter value do not changes on Button Click in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I got a problem in Java using GUI. I used the counter value in **mouse click event** of  a Button, so that the counter value could change each time when we click on Button.

But problem is that it do not work, means that counter value is not changing when we click the button. I also used the **Button action performed event** but still counter value is not changing...

Please someone help me, I would be thankful ...
Here is the code. Check it out . . .

```
private void jButton4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      

    int count=0;
    if(count<questions1.length)
    {
           System.out.println(count);

           jLabel4.setText(questions1[count]);
           jLabel5.setText(answers1[count]);
    }      
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Because `count` is 0 everytime you click the button. Move `int count = 0;` outside of the method as a class variable.

Comment: We do not know what 'is not working' means. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34513411/edit) your post to share all information which might be helpful to us in providing answers.

Comment: I mean "count" value is still not changing when we make it class variable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Recommended solution:

The primary solution is as @CubeJockey stated in OP comments, and as of [@AlexandrRadchykov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34513452/1253136): Have the `count` variable in a higher scope (probably as a class-wide variable).

---

### An alternative solution:

There is a second solution, depending on your use-case, which is to not have the `int` variable at all, and parse from a previous state.

Note however, that this is less CPU-efficient (and insignificantly better Memory-wise) than the primary method, and is only appropriate for low-traffic methods/events (which seems to be the case for the OP). And it also depends on the `JLabel`'s (or whatever component's you're outputting to) text format.

Consider that the `JLabel`'s text is the counter itself:

```
private void jButtonCounterMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
  int count = Integer.parseInt(jLabelCounter.getText());
  count += 1;
  jLabelCounter.setText(count);
  //Condensed: jLabelCounter.setText(Integer.parseInt(jLabelCounter.getText()) + 1);
}
```

So if the format of the content of the `questions1[index]` array includes an index, the same *parse-from-text* technique can be applied. Consider a `questions[]` syntax of `"1. How are you?"`, with index at the start, being split from the rest of the text based on `"."`, `":"` or `")"` (Regex: `"\\.|\\:|\\)"`):

```
private void jButtonCounterMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
  int index = Integer.parseInt(jLabel4.getText().split("\\.|\\:|\\)", 2)[0]);
  if (index < questions1.length) {
    jLabel4.setText(questions1[index]);
  }
  if (index < answers1.length) {
    jLabel5.setText(answers1[index]);
  }
}
```

---

### Some side-notes about the code:

If your `answers1` array is going to always be equivalent to the `questions1` array, it might be better to ***map*** `answers` to their respective `questions`:

```
//Creating map (Note: Since order is important, use a "Linked" map)
Map<String, String> questionsMap = new LinkedHashMap();

//Storing Q&As:
questionsMap.put("Question 1", "Answer 1");
questionsMap.put("Question 2", "Answer 2");
questionsMap.put("Question 3", "Answer 3");

//Getting individual As from Qs (Qs as Object):
questionsMap.get(questionObject);

//=====This might be as follows in your code specifically:
questionsMap.get(jLabel4.getText());

//Getting individual Qs (from index):
questionsMap.keySet().toArray()[index];

//Getting individual As (from index):
questionsMap.values().toArray()[index];

//Getting individual Key-Value pairs (Q-A pairs):
Entry<String, String> entry = (Entry)questionsMap.entrySet().toArray()[index];
entry.getKey(); //Question
entry.getValue(); //Answer

//Iterating through all Key-Value pairs:
for (Entry<String, String> currentEntry : questionsMap.entrySet()){
  currentEntry.getKey(); //Question
  currentEntry.getValue(); //Answer
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should move `count` variable to bigger scope. You can declare it as class instance variable.

Comment: can you show your class code (class declaration, class\instance variables and current jButton4MouseClicked method implementation?

Comment: I used your option. I made 'count' as a class  instance variable but still 'count' value is not changing when we click that button.

Comment: Did you remove count variable declaration inside the method?

Comment: yes... I already used many time that how count value changes when we click button... But this time it is not working...

Comment: Are sure that method invocation works?  Please provide your code, so I can review it.

Comment: Could be more explanative, but is clear enough to account for the OP's provided information so far. +1. --- I've added an answer with an alternative method and a recommendation (and basic usage instructions) for a single `Map` instead of two separate arrays.